# Construction of a conformal map

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Construct a conformal mapping which maps the unit disc centered at the origin bijectively onto the
whole complex plane minus the positive imaginary axis $\{iy : y \geq 0\}$ and which additionally satisfies
$$\lim_{z\to 1} f(z) = 0,\ \text{and}\ f(0) = i.$$
My effort: Because of the given conditions, I considered
$$f(z)=\frac{z-1}{z+i}.$$
I have check this above map is conformal, one-one and satisfying the required conditions.
But I am doubtful about bijectivity of this map. Have I started correctly? If not, please correct me.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to make sense: if $f(0) = i$, then the image of the mapping includes a point on the positive imaginary axis.

Comment: The map you have is a Möbius transformation. Those are always bijective.